# Method to predict the outcome of kidney using the number of inflammatory cells in the glomeruli

Tags: predictive-models

I have a series of renal specimens. In each specimen, it contains a number of glomeruli, and in each glomeruli, there is a number of inflammatory cells. Each specimen belongs to a patient with one of the two conditions. So the data I collect would be like this

```
| ID   | Number of inflammatory cells in glomeruli | Outcome  |
|----- |-------------------------------------------| ---------|
| 1    | 2,2,2,5,6,9,10                            | Improve  |
| 2    | 2,2,2,5,6,9,10,16,18,24                   | Progress |
| 3    | 2,3,2,5,7,9,10,15                         | Improve  |
| 4    | 2,3,5,7,9,16,45                           | Improve  |
| 5    | 2,3,3,4,4,5,7,9,15,16,23,34,45            | Progress |
```

...

I would like to find a method to predict if a patient will improve or progress based on the number of inflammatory cells in glomeruli. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a biological reason why you do not have the same number of glomeruli per patient, or only an experimental reason ?

Comment: How is the outcome variable, "improve" vs "progress", defined?

Comment: Because the kidney sample obtain from different patients may not have the same number of glomeruli. Same may have more, some may be less.

Comment: We follow up the patient for a few months, and compare the blood test if the creatinine level drop (improve) or elevated (progress).

Comment: Is it only because of the sampling that some have more and some have less ? Or is this a biological parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of the data, please correct me if I am wrong :
Each line of your table is one patient. In the second column, between each coma is a number of inflammatory cells in one given glomerulus (between 2 comas = 1 glomerulul). You want to know whether the outcome "improve" or "progress" is influenced by the number of inflammatory cells per glomerulus. Then this outcome is a binomial response variable.

In my opinion there are 2 solutions.

- There seems to be quite some variability in the number of glomeruli sampled per individual. You could make a mean of the number of inflammatory cells per glomeruli and have this as an explanatory variable in a GLM for a binomial distribution. In R it would look like this :
  glm(outcome ~ mean number of inflammatory cells per glomerulus, family=binomial)
- Or you could have 1 line in the table per glomerulus. It means you will have several lines per individual, i.e. several lines with the same value for "ID". The in one column the number of inflammatory cells in this glomerulus. Then the column outcome also will contain several times the same value per individual. Then I would put the individual as a random factor in a GLMer.  It would look a bit like this :
  glmer(outcome~number of inflammatory cells +(1|ID), family=binomial)

Comment: Your interpretation of the data are correct.

Comment: It seems the first one is easier to approach. I will try this first. Thanks.